# get the xmlnodes from soap response whose child node value is 1 using descendant and name()

Tags: xml, soap, nodelist, descendant

Hi all I this xml soap response below coming from a webservice ,what I need is to get the xmlnodelist where Treatmenttype = 1 under "IncomingApplications" parent node , I have acheived to get a xmlnodelist of all "IncomingApplications" by use of this code below

```
  XmlNodeList xmlnode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//soap:Body/descendant::*[name()='IncomingApplications']", nsmgr);
```

Now i want to change the above xpath in such a way that it return IncomingApplications nodes whose child i.e TreatmentType = 1 ,  any help pleas how to change the xpath to get the result ?

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetIncomingApplicationsDataResponse xmlns="http://test.com/webservices/service">
      <GetIncomingApplicationsDataResult>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
          <InDataSet xmlns="http://test.com/webservices/xyzConfigWS/InDataSet.xsd">
            <IncomingApplications diffgr:id="InApp1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
              <SiteName>Test</SiteName>
              <QueueId>1501</QueueId>
              <ApplicationId>3362546</ApplicationId>
              <CountryId>1</CountryId>
              <HoldingQueueId>33625460</HoldingQueueId>
              <CallbackQueueId>3366025</CallbackQueueId>
              <TreatmentType>0</TreatmentType>
              <UnderThresholdQueueId>33625460</UnderThresholdQueueId>
              <IVRGroup>IVR</IVRGroup>
            </IncomingApplications>
            <IncomingApplications diffgr:id="InApp2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
              <SiteName>Test</SiteName>
              <QueueId>1501</QueueId>
              <ApplicationId>3362600</ApplicationId>
              <CountryId>1</CountryId>
              <HoldingQueueId>33626000</HoldingQueueId>
              <CallbackQueueId>3366025</CallbackQueueId>
              <TreatmentType>0</TreatmentType>
              <UnderThresholdQueueId>33626000</UnderThresholdQueueId>
              <IVRGroup>IVR</IVRGroup>
            </IncomingApplications>
            <IncomingApplications diffgr:id="InApp3" msdata:rowOrder="2">
              <SiteName>Test</SiteName>
              <QueueId>1501</QueueId>
              <ApplicationId>3362769</ApplicationId>
              <CountryId>1</CountryId>
              <HoldingQueueId>33627690</HoldingQueueId>
              <CallbackQueueId>3366025</CallbackQueueId>
              <TreatmentType>1</TreatmentType>
              <UnderThresholdQueueId>33627690</UnderThresholdQueueId>
              <IVRGroup>IVR</IVRGroup>
            </IncomingApplications>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
      </GetIncomingApplicationsDataResult>
    </GetIncomingApplicationsDataResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: anyone with some suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Got answer from other forum , here is the solution using linq to xml rather then xpath

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("SampleFile.xml");

string nameSpaceToSearch = @"http://test.com/webservices/xyzConfigWS/InDataSet.xsd";
var result = (from xElement in xDoc.Descendants(XName.Get("IncomingApplications", nameSpaceToSearch))
                where xElement.Element(XName.Get("TreatmentType", nameSpaceToSearch)).Value == "1"
                select xElement);